# Why do $\frac{k !}{\alpha_{1} ! \ldots \alpha_{n} !}$ k-tuples $ \left(i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}\right)$ k-tuples exist?

Tags: real-analysis, statistics

Consider the indices $ \left(i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}\right) $.  Let every index $j\in \{ i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k} \}$ occurs exactly $\alpha_j$ times.
Then in the book it is stated that there are  $\frac{k !}{\alpha_{1} ! \ldots \alpha_{n} !}$ k-tuples $ \left(i_{1}, \ldots, i_{k}\right)$ of numbers with $1\leq i_k \leq n$ in which the index $j$ occurs exactly $\alpha_j$ times.
I don't understand how they come to this conclusion about the amount of k-tuples. Can someone elaborate on that statement?

Note:
$|k|=\alpha_{1}+...+\alpha_{n}$

Comment: I take it that even the case $n=2$ is unknown to you? I.e. the usual formula for counting combinations? $$\begin{pmatrix} m \\ j \end{pmatrix} = \frac{m!}{j! (m-j)!}$$

Comment: I read about it. I also found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_ways_to_put_objects_into_bins but I don't understand how to use this knowledge for the case $\frac{k !}{\alpha_{1} ! \ldots \alpha_{n} !}$. I will try again tomorrow, it seems, like I'm too tired